# does a generic method overrides a none generic method of the fathers class in java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, overriding

```
class A123 {
    public void foo(String str) {
        System.out.println("1");
    }
}

class B123 extends A123 {
    
    public <T> void foo(T item) {
        System.out.println("2");
    }
}
```

I thought that when running the following:

```
public class Test123 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        B123 b = new B123();
        b.foo("test");
    }
}
```

I thought that by sending a string to b.foo the compiler puts "String" type in the T, and then it will be overriding, and b.foo("test") will print 2, but it actually prints "1".
Why is that?

And more than that:
if I have the opposite -

```
class A123 {
    public <T>void foo(T item) {
        System.out.println("1");
    }
}

class B123 extends A123 {
    public void foo(String str) {
        System.out.println("2");
    }
}
```

and I run:

```
public class Test123 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A123 b = new B123();
        b.foo("test");
    }
}
```

(I have a A123 pointer to b)
so the foo in B123 does not override the foo in A, and "1" is printed.

Comment: posted codes should not even compile "*The method foo(String) of type B123 must override or implement a supertype method*" or, depending on compiler, "*method does not override or implement a method from a supertype*"

Comment: You are right, I have edited it, you shouldn't put the "@Override" above the foo in B123. But the question still remains. And now I have another question to figure out:) what does the "@Override" mean so much? It is more than a sign probably-you see.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler picks the *most specific* method signature that matches.

Here, `String` is as specific as it gets. Certainly more specific than `T`, which matches anything.

Comment: I understand. Ok. probably the compiler first chooses the methods and only then puts String where ever there is T.
And in the second code - there is no dynamic linking - why? I guess it is because of the same reason. so I shouldn't get confused by the timing of when the compiler puts Strinf in T.